# Yugabyte - INSERT/UPDATE operations are ACID?

Tags: database, acid, yugabytedb

Below is the schema in yugabyte DB:

```
ycqlsh:example> CREATE TABLE users(user_id INT PRIMARY KEY, full_name TEXT) WITH default_time_to_live = 0 AND transactions = {'enabled': 'false'};     

ycqlsh:example> CREATE TABLE entities(entity_id INT PRIMARY KEY, full_name TEXT) WITH default_time_to_live = 0 AND transactions = {'enabled': 'false'};
```

---

Version:

```
[ycqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.9-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4]
```

---

Queries are initiated through multiple threads in the app

Does insert/update queries on `users` & `entities` table ensure ACID properties?

Answer (score 1):

You are using YugabyteDB's YCQL API, which is based on Cassandra.
The tables are created with transactions = {'enabled': 'false'}, so this means you explicitly turned transactions, alias ACID properties off.

Comment: Does `transactions = {'enabled': 'true'}` ensure ACID properties on?

Comment: Yes, when transactions are enabled for YCQL / YugabyteDB via the Cassandra API, it ensures ACID compliance. Read more about it here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/develop/learn/acid-transactions-ycql/